# Crash casting WKNSURLRequest as? other type

Tags: swift, casting

I'm getting a hard crash when I try to cast WKNSURLRequest (and other classes, all from the WebKit framework).

e.g. in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

final class Sigh: NSObject { }

NSClassFromString("NSObject") as? Sigh.Type

NSClassFromString("WKNSURLRequest") as? Sigh.Type
```

The cast from NSObject works (i.e. returns `nil`), but the cast from WKNSURLRequest crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS - I would have assumed that it would return `nil` as well.

Anyone got any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WKNSURLRequest` does not inherit from `NSObject`

```
@interface WKNSURLRequest : WKObject <NSCopying>
```

And `WKObject` is a root class:

```
NS_ROOT_CLASS
@interface WKObject <WKObject>
```

Unlike Java, where all classes **must** inerhit from `Object`, Obj-C does not require all classes to inherit from `NSObject`.

The Swift<->Obj-C bridge has explicit support for `NSObject` and thus also for its subclasses, but I'm not sure it can handle all other root objects equally well. On the export side (Swift classes being exposed to Obj-C) it's not even possible to make an own root class. A swift class that shall be exposed to Obj-C simply **must** inherit from `NSObject`, so I'd say that the bridge has not been designed with arbitrary root classes in mind.

Of course, none of this explains the crash, which could just be a simple bug in the Swift compiler or the Swift runtime. As you don't reference the classes statically but just by their name, everything happens at runtime and the Swift runtime may just assume that whatever `NSClassFromString` returns is a subclass of `NSObject` and when it then tries to interact with that class, this will fail at runtime because this assumption is plain wrong. In that case it would still be a bug IMHO but it would explain why there is a crash.

Comment: The return of NSClassFromString is an AnyClass. We are checking the return of NSClassFromString, not the class itself. You can do the same experiment with NSProxy, it would not crash. The runtime is not broken and I will prove soon in another question that I will open soon. I will post the link here as I would like you to give your opinion about it.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza I hope you meant to say "The return of NSClassFromString is an AnyClass?" ;-) And that `NSProxy` does not crash could also just mean that the bridge has explicit support for it (`NSProxy` is a quite important standard class and w/o that Swift could not work together with Obj-C). I know lots of Obj-C code calling `isKindOfClass:` or `respondsToSelector:` on objects of type `id`, note that his will crash for root classes that don't implement these methods (and they don't have to) - if you want to be really save, there is very little you can do with an unknown Obj-C class.

Comment: Would you give me your opinion when you have time? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43280615/1754559